# C# WPF Datagrid: Get value from SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

This has been driving me crazy all day. I just want the value of the selected row in a datagrid, it works in VB.net, I'm a little new to c# and I can't get it to work.

In VB my working code is:

```
Private Sub dg_qc_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)

        Dim TempListItem As QCProperties = CType(sender, DataGrid).SelectedItem

        Dim temp1 As String = TempListItem.PartNumber

End Sub
```

In C# I have:

```
    private void dg_blockList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgProperties tempItems = ((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem;

        string tempModel = tempItems.modelRev;
        string tempDate = tempItems.date;
    }
```

I get the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to "my properties class" (are you missing a cast?)

I have searched the internet and I have had no luck, I know its a simple fix. Please help.

Thanks,
 Chelsey

Comment: why is this tagged wpf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to cast the SelectedItem to the right type:

```
dgProperties tempItem = ((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem as dgProperties;
```

Note that you should check to make sure tempItems != null before accessing properties like modelRev and date.

Comment: This is perfect for those who have created their own model. Thanks.